# php variable inside echo 'html code'

Tags: php, html

I have php file index.php

In this file to use html code I am doing:

index.php

```
echo '
<div>
<a class="fragment" href="">
<div>';
```

In href I want to put value of some php variable i.e. `$url`  **How could be done?**

is this correct way?

```
 <a class="fragment" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You concatenate the string by ending it and starting it again:

```
echo '
<div>
<a class="fragment" href="' . $url . '">
<div>';
```

Though I personally prefer to stop the PHP tags and start them again (if I have a lot of HTML) as my IDE won't syntax highlight the HTML as it's a string:

```
?>
    <div>
        <a class="fragment" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">link</a>
    </div>
<?php
```

Comment: What if the div is being imported with php from a different php file? By me, it just outputs "echo..." as text, in the html tag.

Comment: @DaniSpringer Makes no difference - You're probably using the wrong containing quotes or you're reading the php file rather than loading its content with `include` or `require`.

Comment: aha. I'm trying to import the meta tags and define the values with which to fill them, in the pages themselves. But when I write the variable names in the file that I want to import, I get an error saying those variables aren't defined.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/pass-local-variables-to-included-php-filetemplate/

Comment: @DaniSpringer [Global variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) have absolutely nothing to do with pasting variables into an URL.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you for your help! If you are interested: https://github.com/DaniSpringer/Projects/commit/1b96617fb970f23026d876f46c2b9dcb24ad023b

Answer (score 6):

Since you are printing several lines of HTML, I would suggest using a [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) as such:

```
echo <<<HTML
<div>
<a class="fragment" href="$url">
<div>
HTML;
```

`HTML` can be anything as long as you use the same tag both in the beginning and the end. The end tag *must* however be on its own line without any spaces or tabs. With that said, specifically `HTML` also has the benefit that some editors (e.g. VIM) recognise it and apply HTML syntax colouring on the text instead of merely coluring it like a regular string.

If you want to use arrays or similar you can escape the variable with `{}` as such:

```
echo <<<HTML
<div>{$someArray[1]}</div>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are echoing php directly into html i like to do this

```
<div><?=$variable?></div>
```

much shorter than writing the whole thing out (php echo blah blah)

if you are writing html in php directly then there several options

```
$var = '<div>'.$variable.'</div>';   // concatenate the string
$var = "<div>$variable</div>";       // let php parse it for you.  requires double quotes
$var = "<div>{$variable}</div>";     // separate variable with curly braces, also requires double quotes
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like

```
<?php
$url='http://www.stackoverflow.com';
echo "<div><a class='fragment' href='$url' /></div>";
```

Comment: Put single quotes around `$url` and I'll upvote, as I like interpolating rather than concatenating.

Comment: @Barmar, PHP can interpret variables inside quotes too right ?

Comment: @Barmar PHP doesn't expand variables in single quotes.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Single quotes inside double quotes don't prevent variable expansion.

Comment: @Barmar Ah sorry - misunderstood you. I thought you wanted him to enclose the entire thing in single quotes. It's getting late :-)

Comment: E.g. `"blah href='$url' blah"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the echo statement you can do either

```
echo '<a class="fragment" href="'.$url.'"><div>';
```

or

```
echo "<a class=\"fragment\" href=\"$url\">";
```

The first is better for performances and IMHO is more readable as well.

Comment: Ugh, why do people prefer `\"` instead of using single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to input/output large blocks of HTML with embedded variables you can simplify the process by using [Heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
echo <<<_EOI_
<div>
   <a class="fragment" href="$url">
<div>
_EOI_;
```

You don't have to worry about escaping quotes, constant concatenation, or that ugly dropping in and out of `<?php echo $var; ?>` that people do.