# PHP Variable Inside HTML style tag

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using `PHP 5.3.29` on a `WordPress 4.7.4` Site.

I want to change backgrounds based on the time of day.
I found this this code [here](http://wpquestions.com/Change_background_image_on_my_site_depending_on_time_of_day/9283)

I have php file header.php

In this file to use html code I am doing:

header.php:

```
<?php
    $time = date("H");    
    if( $time >= 06 && $time < 10 )
        $img_name = 'sunrise.jpg';
    if( $time >= 10 && $time < 17 )
        $img_name = 'day.jpg';
    if( $time >= 17 && $time < 19 )
        $img_name = 'sunset.jpg';
    if( $time >= 19 && $time < 6 )
        $img_name = 'night.jpg';
?>

<style>
    body.custom-background{background-image:url('http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/<?php echo $img_name;?>');}
</style>
```

I'm not seeing the $img_name variable passed into this style tag
http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/

I think its similar to this post
[php variable inside echo 'html code'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773738/php-variable-inside-echo-html-code)

I took a stab at using Heredocs with no luck:

testing using Heredocs

```
<?php
    $time = date("H");    
    if( $time >= 06 && $time < 10 )
        $img_name = 'sunrise.jpg';
    if( $time >= 10 && $time < 17 )
        $img_name = 'day.jpg';
    if( $time >= 17 && $time < 19 )
        $img_name = 'sunset.jpg';
    if( $time >= 19 && $time < 6 )
        $img_name = 'night.jpg';
?>
echo <<<_EOI_
<style>
    body.custom-background{background-image:url('http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/"$img_name"');}
</style>
_EOI_;
```

Comment: use double quotes instead of single in `url()`

Comment: Alive to Die: THANK YOU!!! I could have sworn I tried that value with double quotes! You're awesome!!!!

Comment: use `${$img_name}` instead of `"$img_name" ` and you are also closing the  php tag before `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single in `url()` and it will fine

```
body.custom-background{background-image:url('http://aarondc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/"$img_name"');}
```

Comment: Thank you again! This is my first time having a question answered.