# js onclick event doesn't work on td element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to create popup div(named `linkdiv` holding `linkcontent` div) on `td` click which is using this function:

```
function getLinks(lid) {
  document.getElementById('linkdiv').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('linkdiv').style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('linkcontent').innerHTML = "<div align=center><img src='images/spacer.gif' border=0 height=280 width=10 alt=''><br><img src='images_v2/loading.gif' border=0 alt='Loading content'></div>";
  var lurl = "viewlinksdiv.php?lid="+lid;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    reql = new XMLHttpRequest;
  } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    reql = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if(reql) {
    reql.onreadystatechange = getLinkResp;
    reql.open("GET",lurl,true);
    reql.send(null);
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHttpRequest technology!");
    doesNotSupport = false;
  }
}
```

and the `td` is..

```html
echo "
<tr>
  <td width=240 height=20 align=\ "left\" valign=\ "top\" style=\ "cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;padding-top:".$pad. ";padding-bottom:5px\" onclick=\ "getLinks('".$mid. "');return:false;\"><b class='news_date'>".$mdate."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$cname.$mpol.":</b>&nbsp;
    <font class='news_title'>".$msectname."</font><br>
    <font class='news_date'>".$moretext."</font>
  </td>
</tr>\n";
```

and the div I want to show is

```
<div id="linkdiv">
  <div id="linkdiv_body">

    <div id="tapclose" align="right" onclick="closeLink()" alt="Close">X</div>
    <div id="linkcontent" class="linkdiv_font"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

this function is working with `a href` element like

```
<a class="jslink" href="javascript:getLinks('3975')">link</a>
```

but doesn't work on `td` `onclick` element.
which is weird cause it's using the same function.
Anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: make sure your stylesheet  has a default display on the div that you want to appear.

Comment: like linkdiv{display:none}

Comment: your syntax is wrong for your `td`. You shouldn't close the `"` and use a `<?php ?>` tag instead to display the value, [like in this accepted answer, solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773738/php-variable-inside-echo-html-code)

Comment: Try to `console.log(lid)` in `getLinks(lid)`... You'll see if the function triggers and if the id passed is correct.

Comment: try to check your logs, I think there is some issue with the syntax

Comment: I found the issue which is something linked to the device to hide the links layer on clicking elsewhere on document. Removing that seems to fix the issue tho not sure why it affects one link and not the other.Thank you for helping.

Comment: https://codepen.io/postor/pen/XVaxro  onclick on td works fine, you should check the html soure your php generated

Answer (score 0):

Javascript function is not getting called due to some syntax errors, update your php code with below one. another thing is in your onclick event you have "return:false" it should be "return false"

```
echo "
 <tr>
  <td width=240 height=20 align='left' valign='top' style='cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;padding-top:".$pad. ";padding-bottom:5px' onclick=\"getLinks('".$mid. "');return false;\"><b class='news_date'>".$mdate."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$cname.$mpol.":</b>&nbsp;
   <font class='news_title'>".$msectname."</font><br>
   <font class='news_date'>".$moretext."</font>
  </td>
 </tr>\n";
```

and working example is below

```js
function getLinks(lid) {
  alert("called");
  document.getElementById('linkdiv').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('linkdiv').style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('linkcontent').innerHTML = "<div align=center><img src='images/spacer.gif' border=0 height=280 width=10 alt=''><br><img src='images_v2/loading.gif' border=0 alt='Loading content'></div>";
  var lurl = "viewlinksdiv.php?lid="+lid;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    reql = new XMLHttpRequest;
  } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    reql = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if(reql) {
    reql.onreadystatechange = getLinkResp;
    reql.open("GET",lurl,true);
    reql.send(null);
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHttpRequest technology!");
    doesNotSupport = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;padding-top:10;padding-bottom:5px" onclick="getLinks('9999');return false;" width="240" valign="top" height="20" align="left"><b class="news_date">1/1/2017&nbsp;&nbsp;TestTestMPol:</b>&nbsp;
    <font class="news_title">Test</font><br>
    <font class="news_date">More</font>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

you can click on "TestTestMPol" and you will see a alert.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have updated my answer with more explanation. Please check it